Elasticsearch query _search : is there a way to get _source documents from aggregations buckets result key id?
I would like to avoid parent/child solution and I am wondering if in a single query/request I can return some documents.
I have documents "rate":
{ id="123", docType="rate", "grade":100}
{ id="456", docType="rate", "grade":0}
{ id="789", docType="rate", "grade":45}

I have documents "topics":
{ id="abc", docType="topic", "title":"Alien"}
{ id="def", docType="topic", "title":"Suspiria"}
{ id="a12", docType="topic", "title":"Ring"}

All documents are in the same index.
_search Request (to improve) is:
    {
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "docType": {
                            "value": "rate"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "_source": false,
    "aggs": {
        "Topics": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "topicId",
                "size": 2
            },
            "aggs": {
                "Grades": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "grade"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Response is:
{
    "took": 9,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 10000,
            "relation": "gte"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "Topics": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 25511,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "abc", <---------------------------------- here
                    "doc_count": 3,
                    "Grades": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": 100,
                                "doc_count": 2
                            },
                            {
                                "key": 0,
                                "doc_count": 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "def", <---------------------------------- here
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "Grades": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": 0,
                                "doc_count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "key": 100,
                                "doc_count": 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

I am wondering if it is possible to have a query/request to get (via "script" or any other solution, or another query ^^) _source documents from the aggregations ("topic" documents) by the result key id returned (see "<--------- here" above)
Excepted top hits returned documents _source response I would like:
.../...
    _source .../...: 
        { id="abc", docType="topic", "title":"Alien"}
        { id="def", docType="topic", "title":"Suspiria"}
.../...


https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html
composite aggs can help

Thank you @MusabDogan. I will explore this part of the documentation. but it seems complex to prepare the query.

You're welcome David, nope it's not complex. Ask chatGPT for an example, you will see how simple it is :)

Not working : https://chatgpt.com/c/0c3fc2b3-695d-4241-bbcd-a37994a8e585
On chatGBPit is good but in real test, topics are not returned. ;) It returns only rate.
I modify to : `"query": {
"bool": {
"should": [
{
"terms": {
"docType":
["rate", "topic"]
      }
    }
  ]
}

},...` but nor working too

Well I have some read here and there and it seems impossible to access "key" of buckets aggs or  to return multiple _source docs...

adding an answer to your question. top_hits aggs.

If you want to see the _source of the aggs results you can use top_hits aggs.
Here is an example for you.
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "rates_and_topics", "_id" : "123" } }
{ "id": "123", "docType": "rate", "grade": 100 }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "rates_and_topics", "_id" : "456" } }
{ "id": "456", "docType": "rate", "grade": 0 }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "rates_and_topics", "_id" : "789" } }
{ "id": "789", "docType": "rate", "grade": 45 }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "rates_and_topics", "_id" : "abc" } }
{ "id": "abc", "docType": "topic", "title": "Alien" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "rates_and_topics", "_id" : "def" } }
{ "id": "def", "docType": "topic", "title": "Suspiria" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "rates_and_topics", "_id" : "a12" } }
{ "id": "a12", "docType": "topic", "title": "Ring" }

POST rates_and_topics/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "docType": {
        "value": "rate"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id.keyword",
        "size": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "NAME": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Edit: The composite aggs.
GET rates_and_topics/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "id.keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "doc_type": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "docType.keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "grade": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "grade"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}


Thank you but this is not the correct answer to the question...

You're welcome David. If you like me to answer to your question better, please give me more details about what you are looking for. I saw what is the expected output from your question and composite aggregation looks fit for you. I updated my answer please check agian

Thank you Musab for the Edit "The composite aggs" but I got 0 results. `{
"took": 23,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 1,
"successful": 1,
"skipped": 0,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": {
"value": 10000,
"relation": "gte"
},
"max_score": null,
"hits": []
},
"aggregations": {
"NAME": {
"buckets": []
}
}
}

It can be because of your index mapping. Please try the example I shared and compare the differences between two index. Especially the field types.
